# How do I bulk import Communication/Privacy preferences?

Tags: data-import

I want to import a large group of people and some of them have opted out of SMS communications and some have opted out of email communications. I have tried multiple ways of entering the fields in my CSV files and none of them will import properly.  For example, I created a column "Do Not Email" and in the field for those who wanted do not want to receive email I put "YES" and the file imported properly, but the contact record does not say Do Not Email. What is the correct way to add this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the number "1" for yes and a blank for no.

One way to see this is if you do an export and then look at how it outputs it.

Comment: THANK YOU! Looked everywhere in the guides as to what values would work in the field.

Comment: @cynthia Could you submit a documentation update?  It's quite simple: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-civicrm-community/contributing-to-this-manual/#single_changes